# Verifying that a mass amount of email addresses exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I have a list of over 47,000 email addresses and need to check which ones exist.

I don't want to pay for a service as the cheapest offer I could find was 42usd.

I searched through SO and what I gathered was that its possible but if you do it in massive amounts, sites like hotmail, gmail, yahoo, etc. will block you from it?

Is there some way I could get around this and verify these emails as quick as possible? Is there any easy way to do this?

I know python, javascript, and bash at an intermediate level, so if its easier to do it from a different language then thats fine.

Comment: I would actually start with checking if the domain of the email exists first. You might be able to cut the list down considerably. Then work on checking if the actual email exists with the remainder.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'll do that